# iPhone/iPad custom menu

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I was trying to find out how Facebook's application MENU works on iPhone and iPad. Once you press the button at the top left, the main screen moves on the right and the menu appears.
I was trying to create the same menu/effect on xCode but I had no luck.
Do anyone here knows how I can do this? can you redirect me to any website that has that kind of information? Or can you please guide me through on how to make such a menu?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the facebook app was created with this open source framework [three20](https://github.com/facebook/three20)

also if you cannot find what you want in the framework, I suggest building your own UI elements inside UIViews, that appear, dissappear as you want,

good luck!